# lineWidth not rendering Bezier curve width correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, bezier

I am using lineWidth to create a circle with stroke width 4. I am using UIBezierPath for creating the circle. But, due to some reason, lineWidth is always rendering a circle with a thin stroke no matter what value I assign to lineWidth. I have also tried to put path.lineWidth = 100.0, but no change in stroke width.

This is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(progressView.frame.size.width, progressView.frame.size.height), NO, 0.0);

    [[UIColor colorWithRed:246.0/255.0 green:80.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(progressView.frame.size.width/2 ,progressView.frame.size.height/2) radius:progressView.frame.size.width/2 - 5 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) clockwise:YES];
    [path stroke];
    path.lineWidth = 4;
UIImage* pathImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [progressView setImage:pathImg];
```

I googled a lot, but could not find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the stroke width before you actually stroke the path:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(progressView.frame.size.width, progressView.frame.size.height), NO, 0.0);
[[UIColor colorWithRed:246.0/255.0 green:80.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] setStroke];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(progressView.frame.size.width/2 ,progressView.frame.size.height/2) radius:progressView.frame.size.width/2 - 5 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) clockwise:YES];
path.lineWidth = 4;
[path stroke];
UIImage* pathImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[progressView setImage:pathImg];
```